# How to get data from facebook Ads on the Graph API?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am new to PHP and facebook API'S

I am trying to get data from my ads account on faceobook using PHP

I just want to know how much $ every ads spent

First of all - I did not understand if I must have facebook app in order to get data from my personal ad account ?

I assumed yes so I created one now..,
I am geting the acess token like this :

```
require_once("facebook.php");

  $config = array();
  $config['appId'] = 'myapp_id';
  $config['secret'] = 'myappsecret';
  $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional

  $facebook = new Facebook($config);

  // Set a new app secret
$facebook->setApiSecret($config['secret']);

// If you do above, also set the app id
$facebook->setAppId( $config['appId']);

 $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
```

But when I am trying a get request like this:
https://graph.facebook.com/act_[my_account_number]/adgroups

I am getting a premisson exception that tell me

**An access token is required to request his resource**

But where do I put the access token ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add it at the end of the url as a url parameter:

```
"https://graph.facebook.com/act_[my_account_number]/adgroups" . "?access_token=" . $access_token
```

However, from the code I think you are getting an App Access Token, and you need a Page Access Token or a User Access Token to get the ads related to your Facebook Page.

Please refer to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/ for more information.